# Ошибка телеграм бота aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
counter = 0
number = 0

def rewievs():
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("❤️", callback_data="like")
button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data="dislike")
markup.add(button1,button2)
return markup

async def choseJoke(message):
global counter
global number
if 'jokes' in jokes_data and counter < len(jokes_data['jokes']):
    number = r.randint(0, len(jokes_data['jokes']) - 1)
    if jokes_data['jokes'][number]['counter'] != 1:
        await nahrada('jokes',jokes_data, "jokes.json", number, 'counter')
        counter += 1
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, jokes_data['jokes'][number]['joke'], reply_markup=rewievs())

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'dislike')
async def handle_dislike_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    message = callback_query.message
    await nahrada('jokes',jokes_data, "jokes.json", number, 'bad')
    num = r.randint(0,6) 
    print(num)
    if num <= 2:
        await callback_query.answer(text=jokes_data["badJokePhrase"][num])
        print(num)
    print(num)
    await choseJoke(message)
```

Весь код отрабатывает, но в конце, при вызове функции choseJoke(message) появляется ошибка:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantTalkWithBots: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots
Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде ошибка. Вы написали код и в нём один бот отправляет сообщение другому боту, но это в Python-telegram-bot не доступно. Для решения этой проблемы вы можете изменить код таким образом, чтобы ваш бот отправлял сообщение не другому боту, а напрямую пользователю. Вам нужно заменить message.from_user.id на message.chat.id в вызове функции bot.send_message. Вот исправленный код:

```
async def choseJoke(message): 
global counter 
global number 
if 'jokes' in jokes_data and counter < len(jokes_data['jokes']): 
    number = r.randint(0, len(jokes_data['jokes']) - 1) 
    if jokes_data['jokes'][number]['counter'] != 1: 
        await nahrada('jokes',jokes_data, "jokes.json", number, 'counter') 
        counter += 1 
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, jokes_data['jokes'][number]['joke'], reply_markup=rewievs()) 

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'dislike') 
async def handle_dislike_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery): 
message = callback_query.message 
await nahrada('jokes',jokes_data, "jokes.json", number, 'bad') 
num = r.randint(0,6)  
print(num) 
if num <= 2: 
    await callback_query.answer(text=jokes_data["badJokePhrase"][num]) 
    print(num) 
print(num) 
await choseJoke(message)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это правда помогло !